# Group by a list of words by their first letter in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have to group by first letter of the word in LINQ. Since i'm new to LINQ i'm not aware of debugging into it.

//Code

```
var words4 = testDS.Tables["Words4"].AsEnumerable();

var wordGroups =
    from w in words4
    group w by w.Field<string>("word")[0] into g
    select new {FirstLetter = g.Key, Words = g };

foreach (var g in wordGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Words that start with the letter '{0}':", g.FirstLetter);  
    Console.WriteLine(g.Field<string>("word"));

}
```

Its throwing "Invalid Arguments" execption in the last Console.WriteLine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Adding a loop inside so you can get the results more accurately.

Replace:

```
Console.WriteLine(g.Field<string>("word"));
```

With:

```
foreach (var w in g.Words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(w.Field<string>("word"));
}
```

Comment: Just for the record (since the topic here was Linq); I believe you could do the same using Linq as follows: `g.Words.ForEach(w => Console.WriteLine(W.Field<string>("word"));`

Comment: @Kjartan Your comment is the answer, not Santhosh's answer.

Comment: @eriawan: But santhosh's code worked for me and moreover he answered me at the right time i clicked him.

Answer (score 1):

Since in your `select`, you created an anonymous object with field specified as `Words` and later you are accessing it through `word`, Also the `Field` extension method is not required.

You need to replace:

```
Console.WriteLine(g.Field<string>("word"));
```

with

```
Console.WriteLine(g.Words);
```

Comment: If he wants some sort of readable output he probably wants: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", g.Words.Select(w => w.Field<string>("word"))));`

Comment: @aquinas, yes, that is true, and IMO it should be an answer as well

Answer (score 1):

First, rather than your group consisting of DataRows, since you only want to show the words, I would select the words you want out of the datarow. Second, remember that the words are in a list. If you want to print them out, you'll need to loop or do something like string.Join (as I do below). For example:

```
var wordGroups =
    from w in words4.Select(w => w.Field<string>("word"))
    group w by w[0] into g
    select new { FirstLetter = g.Key, Words = g };

foreach (var g in wordGroups) {
    Console.WriteLine("Words that start with the letter '{0}':", g.FirstLetter);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", g.Words));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fetch what you want from within `wordGroups`, using **Linq syntax:**

Replace:

```
Console.WriteLine(g.Field<string>("word"));
```

with:

```
g.Words.ForEach(w => Console.WriteLine(W.Field<string>("word"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be something like this?

```
Dictionary<string, List<Product>> groupedDictionary = _db.Products.GroupBy(g => g.Name.Substring(0,1)).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```